# PreSaveAction for Quick Edit Mode

Tags: 2016, jsom, client-side-rendering, presaveaction

I have build some scripts running in the PreSaveAction function for example to validate some data or conditionaly send an email via ajax call. Now I need this functionality when the user creates a new item or edit an item through **quick edit mode**. 
Is there something equivalent to that function or does anyone know how to solve this issue? After long time of searching maybe I could find some help here and don't need to do it with an event receiver. Thx

```
//https://www.spjeff.com/2014/05/17/quick-edit-supports-js-link-and-client-side-rendering/
(function () {
    var overrideContext= {};
    overrideContext.Templates = {};
    overrideContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "Module": {
            "View": setDefaultValue
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
})();
function setDefaultValue(ctx) {
    var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);
    var validators = new SPClientForms.ClientValidation.ValidatorSet(); 
    if(ctx.CurrentItem.Module != ""){
        if(ctx.CurrentItem.Module[0].lookupValue != 'Aussenanlage'){
                ret = "<div style='color: white; background-color: lightgreen'>"
        + " <img src='http://sharepoint.***/_layouts/15/images/kpinormal-0.gif' /> " 
        + ctx.CurrentItem.Module[0].lookupValue;
        + "</div>";
        }
        else {
                ret = "<div style='color: black; background-color: yellow'>"
        + " <img src='http://sharepoint.***/_layouts/15/images/kpinormal-0.gif' /> " 
        + ctx.CurrentItem.Module[0].lookupValue;
        + "</div>";     
        }               
    }
    else {
        ret = "";
    }   
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try to use CSR (client side rendering) for validation purposes and workflows for email sending.
CSR like here:
https://sii.pl/blog/client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint/ 
https://julieturner.net/2015/08/jslink-validation-from-basic-to-advanced/ 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/magazine/dn745867.aspx
https://www.softlanding.ca/about-Softlanding/resources/blog/field-validation-client-side-rendering 
Search "RegisterValidator" in text of this articles.
May be it is applicable to Quick Edit view.

### UPDATED:

Yes, you can use CSR for validation in Quick Edit mode and to change your cell (column row intercept) control to some new control with new features. But I doesn't have fully completed code for that.
At these links I found ways to change quick edit column control to other and set validation to them. [1](http://sharepointbitsandbytes.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-quick-edit-javascript-validation/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48588562/10745346), [3](https://chuvash.eu/2014/11/27/jsgrid-basics/). 
You can create code like below. Warning - it is not competed to correctly validate your field. It is my code, I tested it, it is working, but not completed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// https://chuvash.eu/2014/11/27/jsgrid-basics/
// http://sharepointbitsandbytes.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-quick-edit-javascript-validation/
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/48588562/10745346
var QuickEditTestNamespace = QuickEditTestNamespace || {};
QuickEditTestNamespace.IsContolValueValid = function (value) {
    // TODO: custom validation logic
    var isContolValueValid = !!value && value === 'MyValidValue';
    return isContolValueValid;
};
QuickEditTestNamespace.handleGridMode = function (ctx, field) {
    var currentFieldSchema = ctx.CurrentFieldSchema;
    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
        SP.GanttControl.WaitForGanttCreation(function (ganttChart) {
            var targetColumn = null;
            var editId = "EDIT_CONTROL_ADVANCED_" + currentFieldSchema.Name.toUpperCase();
            var columns = ganttChart.get_Columns();

            for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
                if (columns[i].columnKey == currentFieldSchema.RealFieldName) {
                    targetColumn = columns[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (targetColumn) {

                targetColumn.fnGetEditControlName = function (record, fieldKey) {
                    return editId;
                };
                SP.JsGrid.PropertyType.Utils.RegisterEditControl(editId, function (gridContext, cellControl) {

                        var newEditControl = new SP.JsGrid.EditControl.EditBoxEditControl(gridContext, null);

                        newEditControl.SetValue = function (value) {
                            debugger;
                            var _cellContext = newEditControl.GetCellContext();
                            newEditControl._cellContext = _cellContext;

                            var isContolValueValid = QuickEditTestNamespace.IsContolValueValid(value);
                            if (isContolValueValid == true) {
                                _cellContext.SetCurrentValue({ localized: value });
                            } else {
                                gridContext.jsGridObj.SetCellError(_cellContext.record.recordKey, currentFieldSchema.RealFieldName, "Your field is INVALID!");
                            }
                        };

                        newEditControl.Unbind = function () {
                            debugger;
                            _cellContext = newEditControl._cellContext;

                            if (_cellContext != null) {
                                gridContext.jsGridObj.ClearAllErrorsOnCell(_cellContext.record.recordKey, currentFieldSchema.RealFieldName);
                            }
                        };

                        return newEditControl;

                }, []);
            }

        });
    }, "spgantt.js");
};
QuickEditTestNamespace.fieldProcessor = function (ctx, field) {
    var fieldValue = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]; 
    if (ctx.inGridMode) {
        QuickEditTestNamespace.handleGridMode(ctx, field);
    }
    return fieldValue;
};
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
    var overrideContext = {}; 
    overrideContext.Templates = {}; 
    overrideContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        "LinkTitle": { 
            "View": QuickEditTestNamespace.fieldProcessor 
        } 
    }; 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
});
</script>
```

I don't want to investigate this case to fully completed code but If you have time then you can try. It must worked correctly but I don't know how much time you will spend on this task and may be some bugs exists in this logic =) . May be  you will spend one week or more.

Comment: This "RegisterValidator" topic could be a solution. I'll give it a try. thx.

Comment: Hey Vsevolod, thank you for your links. In my case I couldn't find a solution, because the FormContext is always null. I think it's because of the Quick Edit Mode.
I found an article: http://sharepointbitsandbytes.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-quick-edit-javascript-validation/ that can help (maybe). If not I'll solve it by using Remote Event Receiver... my already existing scripts for the new- and edit form than can't be used anymore.

Comment: Can you add your code with FormContext null to your question ? I will try to reproduce later.

Comment: Hi Vsevolod, first thx again. I've added the code that I used just for trial and error and to determine how it works.
Now I decided to write a Remote Event Receiver. It's going well and is working  in quick edit mode too. So, just do it if you are also interested in a client side solution. I would still appreciate.

Comment: OK. Just for you to know.  formCtx is null and SPClientForms can not be found. I think, because it's a view context and not form.

Comment: I tried to create code. See answer. I updated it. formCtx and SPClientForms is not accessible because View is not Form and because that we don't have variables with "form" prefixes and suffixes like this. I found 3 good articles how to change column control in Quick Edit mode. 1 of them how to change control validation. I created code on this articles and specified in answer. This code is working but not completed fully. It must be correctly customized and developed. I don't want to perform this, it is very time consuming task. Sorry. =) May be you need one week to complete it or more.

Comment: You can try to complete this code and post here for next generations. =) Or you can try some other not so time consuming ways but now I don't know what way would be good for you.